# CKAN graphing software is not working properly

Tags: ckan

I'm adding data to a CKAN's DataStore and I'm trying to depict a graph based on two fields within my data. This is the result:

[image]

The graphing software seems not being linking the points quite well... Any idea regarding this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is plotting your data in whatever order your table is, which happens not to be in timestamp order. If that is the case, you could solve that by sorting the rows by timestamp or using a bar chart.

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks for the hint!